# Unable to connect through SSH tunnel

Tags: linux, php, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying to tunnel into a remote server for the purposes of debugging(so I could get a more specific error message rather than internal server error 500), and I was looking at the question: [phpmyadmin forbidden through ssh tunnel](https://serverfault.com/questions/288660/phpmyadmin-forbidden-through-ssh-tunnel)

I tunnel in successfully using the command ssh -L 8080:localhost:80 www.remotesite.com

But, when I try to connect using my browser using the URL www.remotesite.com:8080/ext/test/registration.php I'm unable to connect.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `ssh -L 8080:localhost:80 www.remotesite.com` connects to the server at www.remotesite.com and asks to tunnel localhost:80 (which would be www.remotesite.com itself) to the 8080 port of the client initiating the ssh connection.

In other words: you need to connect to localhost (your own workstation, not the server) on port 8080, that is where the entrance of your tunnel lies.

The URI then becomes: `http://localhost:8080/ext/test/registration.php`